# clarifying mac adress validation using a wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, authentication, mac-address

I have access to an ethernet port which requires a mac address validation and the system only allows one value to be registered at any given time.

If I use a wireless router and register its mac address, will I be able to wirelessly connect other devices to the internet through the router and finally through the ethernet port to which I have access?

(I'm asking because I'm afraid I may commit some mistakes in the setting up and I'd like to be sure that what I want to do is at least theoretically possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, provided you configure the wireless router to use its DHCP server to give out IP addresses to its clients. This will prevent the router from forwarding upstream requests for IP addresses from unregistered clients. Instead, with this setup, all traffic will appear to originate from the wireless router, with any further reference to the addresses of the originating pcs being kept in-house, *i.e.*, inside the router.

The only disadvantage of this is that your router's clients will be in a different subnet than the other devices on the LAN, so that you can access them, but they cannot access your clients. You will have to learn how to open the reverse path (from LAN to your subnet) depending on the router you buy.

But at any rate, remember that it is always possible to change your card's mac address, at least temporarily (meaning: you lose the fake address at reboot). There are utilities to do this in all OSes, just look up yours under *Windows change mac address* or whatever applies to you.

Comment: this is incredibly clear, now I just have to do it. thanks.

Comment: @maja Sorry I forgot: remember that you must keep the LAN net and your subnet completely distinct. So, if the first one is 192.168.1.0/24, setup the second one to be 192.168.233.0/24 or some such thing.

Comment: Allright, it seems the network administrator thought about this and provided static ip's in the 140:xxx:... range